# PrestaShop Add To Cart button not working from single product page

Tags: prestashop, shopping-cart, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

Whenever the client clicks on the "Add To Cart" button from single product page, it simply goes to cart but cart items are not updated. It redirects to this URL /?controller=cart where all items added either from category view or grid view are there but not the one added from single product page.

I just need a hint on what might be the issue. I'm using Prestashop version 1.7.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It is most likely a JS error; open the browser's dev tools -> console and check the errors, you will notice them they're red.